# Purpose of Data.Vector.Mixed

Tags: haskell, vector, ghc

In Edward Kmett's [hybrid-vectors](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hybrid-vectors-0.1.2.1) library, there are two main modules: `Data.Vector.Hybrid` and `Data.Vector.Mixed`. There's a [big article](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/edwardk/revisiting-matrix-multiplication/part-3) written on the motivation behind the former. The latter is mentioned in passing but lacks any explanation. I'm trying to figure out what use case it is for. I've noticed two things so far:

1. There is a `Mixed` typeclass with `Typeable` constraints. I don't understand the explanation in the haddocks, but it seems like the `Typeable` constraints must be needed to recover type information or safely cast at some point.
2. The `Vector` data type is parameterized over only the underlying `MVector`. This is different from the `Hybrid` module where it was parameterized over two vector types plus a tuple.

I would appreciate any helpful insights or (even better) small examples of use cases. Thanks.

Comment: I've never used it before, but I believe the purpose is just to provide operations that work on all combinations of vector types

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand. With operations like `head`, `length`, and `indexM`, this doesn't really by you anything because they only take one vector as an argument (and there are already versions of these functions that work on all the other vector types). But for `zipWith`, it seems somewhat useful because there are two vector arguments. No, I still think I'm missing something.

Comment: Yes, I think it's for things that take more than one vector as an argument.  I'm guessing that the other operations are purely for completeness (so that you don't have to import other modules, too)

Answer (score 1):

It's w/in my understanding that the`Mixed` typesclass would enables uses of type-safety functions to be able to parse, merge and fold through a Vector rather than have a concurrent process where each vector is parsed simsimultaneously thus declare `M.Vector g v M.Vector h m` in order to find a singleton point within these vectors and then using the `for MVector do |Stream.length g v && Stream h m` to find a singleton within each to fold with this key `key :: mergeStreamwith k d -> Stream k i -> Stream d i     instance Singleton key where  key = Vector.singleton[ v->(v-> MVector v m) -> MVector m] do transversewithkey g v =>  key.foldlwithkey g h`